# Refusal of visit visa from nigeria

Tags: uk-citizens, nigerian-citizens

The decision for refusal

Please advise me on when next to apply and how to go about a fresh application without getting refused again, in a few weeks' time I'm going to be through with my university undergraduates course.

[image: first page of refusal form]

Comment: Did you create another account?

Comment: You have already received advice. Posting your same question again will not help.

Answer (score 0):

To get a tourist visa, among other things you have to **convince** the UK officials that you will leave again. For a Nigerian citizen, that can be difficult.

- Get yourself a stable, well-paid job.
- Then get a history of travel to other countries.
- Do not apply *again* in the UK until your circumstances have changed, or you will get another refusal.